# Best way to use AES encryption with HMAC for purely client side encryption/decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm just playing around with a test app to password encrypt some text, then decrypt with the password. I want everything done client-side (currently using CryptoJS).

The issue I'm having is AES has no notion of if the text is decrypted correctly or not. I could decrypt with the wrong password and not know(obviously the text would be unreadable to a human, but the code wouldn't know that). The encoding will throw an error a lot of the time, but not always.

My solution is to use an HMAC as follows.

```
encrypted = AES.encrypt(plaintext, password) // Example: "eNcRyPtEd"
hmac = HmacSHA256(encrypted, password)       // Example: "HMACabc"
return `${encrypted}.${hmac}`                // Example: "eNcRyPtEd.HMACabc"
```

Then the server gets that single string which is comprised of the encrypted text, plus the HMAC, delimited by a `.`.

On decryption:

```
# Get guess from user
password_guess = "user's input"

# Calc HMAC with the password_guess
[encrypted, hmac] = payload.split(".")
newHmac = HmacSHA256(encrypted, password_guess)

# Compare newHmac with the original HMAC
# decrypt or error based on HMAC equality
if newHmac == hmac
  AES.decrypt(encrypted, password_guess)
else
  print "wrong password"
```

This achieves my initial goal, to be able to determine if a password is correct or not, without having to store/send that password, or ever having it leave the client. However I'm not a cryptographer, this was cobbled together from semi-related SO answers and Wikipedia. And this is a project to learn so I'd like to know:

- Are there flaws in this approach?
- Is there a better way to handle this?
- Is there something I can do to improve my current algorithm?

Comment: Why don't you use AES-GCM? [One key to handle all](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84357/18298) still you need a good password and KDF.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: this is probably reasonably secure, but sloppy, and hard to justify based on existing analysis. But also, probably fine.

For a fuller treatment of this approach based on sjcl, see [RNCrytor-js](https://github.com/RNCryptor/rncryptor-js). Your basic approach is fine, though cryptojs is a bit opaque about how it handles passwords (it does it reasonably well; it just doesn't document it very well, and some of its choices haven't been well analyzed by the crypto community, for example reusing the IV as the PBKDF2 salt).

Using the password directly as an HMAC key is also not well analyzed. It's probably reasonably fine, but it's sloppy. Generally you should never reuse a key for two purposes. (In this case, you're not, because the AES key gets stretched, while the HMAC key doesn't, but it's still sloppy).

If you want to build a format like this, you may want to look at the [RNCryptor v4](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/draft-RNCryptor-Spec-v4.0.md) spec. It's never been fully implemented (and there are several unincorporated comments from Maarten Bodewes who is better at this than I am), but it may be a useful starting point. It includes a lot of background that may be useful for building this kind of system. Crypto formats are very subtle, and difficult to build well.

Comment: On the point of using the same password for AES and HMAC. If I only want to ask for a single input from the user, could I use that input to derive two other passwords(I'd look for a better solution, but just for an example: hash it, then split the hash in half), one for AES, and one for HMAC? Or is this no different than using the single user input for both?

Comment: And thank you, I'll dig into RNCryptor. I hadn't come across it before.

Comment: The tool you're looking for is called an HKDF. First stretch the password into a IKM (Initial Keying Material). Then use an HKDF to extract additional keys. The v4 spec includes an explanation of the process. But yes, a simpler approach (and quite secure), would be to use PBKDF2 to stretch the password into 512 bits and then split it into 256 for AES and 256 for HMAC. Every output bit of a PBKDF-stretched key is considered independent, so you can safely split the bits up and use them for independent purposes.

Comment: The current v3 of RNCryptor runs PBKDF2 twice on the password with different salts to generate the two independent keys. This is secure, but very slow, which is why I proposed using HKDF for v4 instead. Also, if you can, you should just use AES-GCM. It solves all of these problems together and has become much more readily available. You don't need a separate HMAC when you use GCM. (You still do require a PBKDF to stretch human-generated passwords, though.)

Comment: Consider one key as HMAC key; [Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76588/18298)

Comment: I 'd be more worried that no PBKDF is used to calculate the HMAC key. That makes the scheme considerably less secure, as the attacker can directly test passwords. Using the same key after PBKDF for HMAC and AES - well, it isn't proven that this is secure, but I would be **very** surprised if anybody can mount an attack based on that.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks again for your comment. I've looked into SJCL.js, and I think `sjcl.encrypt(password, plaintext, { mode: "gcm" })` does everything I need (can handle incorrect passwords), and is a more battle-tested encryption solution. Do I get additional security by providing authenticated data? By default SJCL seems to not use any, and I'm not passing in any. Would a sha256 hash of the plaintext work? `var hash = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(text);` then `var adata = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(hash)` Or is this just redundant?

Comment: AD is extremely useful in some situations, and used correctly it can prevent a number of interesting attacks. But you shouldn't add it unless you have a need for it and make proper use of it. Most common use cases don't need it, however, and it's not something you should just add without a clear purpose. For more about the situations where it's useful, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179273/what-is-the-purpose-of-associated-authenticated-data-in-aead  Probably the most common use is to authenticate unencrypted header information for network protocols.